# 12 V initial to lower voltage continuous step-down circuit

Tags: 12v, solenoid, step-down

How do I design a step-down circuit that hits 12 V initially, but then drops the voltage for continuous use until turned off?

I have a line lock solenoid that requires 12 V to activate. The manufacturer recommends to use it for only 60 seconds at a time. I've learned that you can hit a solenoid with 12 V to pull it closed but then you can lower the voltage to say 5 V to hold it closed, greatly increasing the run time before it gets too hot.

I have a good basic understanding of electronics and know how to read drawings and am handy with a soldering iron - or maybe there is an off-the-shelf option that I can't find. I've only found step-down circuits that are always at the lower voltage.

Would it be safe to have one circuit feeding two solenoids? I'm planning to wire it as 12 V source > missile switch > step down circuit > both solenoids > individually grounded to the chassis.

Comment: Use PWM - look it up if you don't know what it means.

Comment: What you want to do is called holding current reduction, its common in some industrial products I know, yes PWM is the key for a good solution rather than tinkering with the voltage. Tip: a good old ne555 can implement a holding current reduction with PWM quite nice... and its 500mA is sufficient for many devices. Please also note: some uses of holding current reduction in industrial applications might (still) be protected by patents

Answer (score 0):

Your load is a solenoid  which makes things easier. PWM is fine when the frequency is high enough to give smoothish current through the winding inductance but not crazy high where EMC and switching losses will be a problem. You can start with Duty cycle of 100% and finish with say 40%. These days micros are used for low frequency PWM. Sure I have used analog. It’s easy to make say 1 kHz. I have not had audible noise problems with my relays, if you do then 20 kHz is no big deal.

Comment: Make sure the solenoid has just a single diode for the suppression, instead of a fancy RC snubber or a zener diode, else a large amount of heat gets created in the snubber circuit during the off periods

Answer (score 0):

Two different ways.

1. Drive the solenoid through a resistor bypassed with a large capacitor.  The resistor sets the long-term current through the solenoid by creating a voltage divider.  The resistor is the series leg, and the resistance of the solenoid coil is the shunt leg.  For example, with a 12 V coil, if the coil resistance is 24 ohms (for a nominal operating current of 500 mA), then a 24 ohm resistor in series with the coil will reduce the current to 250 mA.  The power dissipated in the resistor is 1.5 W, so use a resistor rated for at least 3 W.

Next, the capacitor in parallel with the resistor.  Initially it is completely discharged, so it acts as a dead short across the resistor, providing the full 500 mA to the coil.  As it charges up, the voltage across it increases, reducing the coil voltage exponentially from 12 V down to 6 V.  So, the larger the capacitor, the longer the coil gets the higher currents.  How long it takes for the coil voltage to decrease to 6 V is up to you.  The resistor and capacitor are an R-C network with a time constant.  The voltage across the resistor will increase from 0 V to 63% of 6 V in 1 time constant, 86% in two time constants, and 95% in three time constants.  Beyond this, the change in coil current is very small.

If we pick 1 second as the time over which the coil voltage changes by 95% (the english gets a bit messy here), then 1 second equals three time constants:

R x C = 0.333

R = 24

Therefore, C = 0.0139 F, or almost 14,000 uF.

That's a lot, but not terrible.  To test whether or not this approach will work successfully, you must know the coil resistance.  For this example, I would start with a 10,000 uF or 15,000 uF / 25 V capacitor and see if the solenoid pulls in reliably.

2. A similar technique, but with a voltage regulator.  By applying the R-C ramp to the adjustment input to a simple linear voltage regulator, the capacitor size can be reduced by 10x to 100x.  In this case, the excess power is dissipated in the regulator's pass transistor rather than in a resistor.

Assuming the 12 V solenoid will pull in reliably on 11 V, the regulator does not have to be very complex:  1 power transistor, 1 capacitor, 2 resistors.  No 555's, no Arduino, no GPS receiver, no decoupling capacitors, no inductive kick (flyback pulse) suppression, no RF noise.

a)  How many circuits do you intend to build?

b)  Where are you located?

c)  got Got GOT to know the coil resistance.